# Why is this variable working in the nav but not in the body tag?

Tags: html, xslt

I have a file called **framework.xsl**. I've never worked with XSL before. I want to give the body the class of the current category.

I found something which can help me in this part:

I saw this section:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <xsl:for-each select="page/departments/row0">
        <li>
            <a href="main-category/{cat_slug}"><xsl:value-of select="cat_name"/></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="arrow"></a>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="row1">
                    <li>
                        <a href="subcategory/{../cat_slug}/{sub_cat_slug}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="sub_cat_name"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

The variable `{cat_slug}` displays the name of the current category.

So I tried to place it in the body tag:

```
</head>
<body class="{cat_slug}">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <xsl:if test="$pms/pagename = 'home' and page/content/row0/f1/text()">
```

But nothing happens. You just get something like `<body class>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the code its nearly impossible to say, however I would guess that at the point where the `body` stub is being generated there is no `cat_slug` child to pull the value from.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `{cat_slug}` isn't actually a variable. Variables are represented using using the `$` symbol. The curly braces indicate it is an "Attribute Value Template" and means it is expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

In this case, looking at the expression within the curly braces, it will be looking for an element called **cat_slug**. This is a relative expression, meaning it expects **cat_slug** to be a child of the element you are currently positioned on.

The first occurrence of its use is this

```
<a href="main-category/{cat_slug}">
```

But this occurs in an **xsl:for-each** when you are iterating over **row0** elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="page/departments/row0">
```

This suggests **cat_slug** is a child element of **row0**. As your `<body>` is most likely outside this **xsl:for-each** loop, it will be looking the element **cat_slug** in a different place, one where is doesn't exist.